# Run a python script residing in EFS from batch script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-efs

I am trying to run the Python script that resides in AWS Elastic file System, using boto3 batch client.

However this is unable to read script file from EFS.

Comment: Please edit your Question to include the code or command that you are using, and show the exact error message so that we can try to reproduce your situation.

Comment: seems more like a file permissions issue. Does the user you are using to run boto3 batch client have execute permission on the file?